# Edge browser opens windows in full screen, after certain height limit

Tags: height, width, microsoft-edge, window.open

Edge browser opens windows in full screen, after certain height limit.I had tried in the screen resolution of 1280*1024 if we set the height>899 open the window in full screen.

Any one facing the same issue? If yes, are there any workarounds?

I have seen there are few issues reported on edge related to height and width. Can some one help